# Computer vision approach to capturing whole paper document frame

Tags: computer-vision

I'd like to understand options for digitally capturing the contents of a piece of paper - exactly positioned.

I have control over the format of the paper so can add markers etc but I need the contents to be captured at exact locations so that I can match this with a template.  The approach will need to compensate for rotation, perspective correction etc as I want to target mobile devices.

I have a solution which employs QR codes to obtain document corner points, but it's a relatively slow process and has some issues, so I'm looking for other potential approaches.